# Who knows what Picasa is programmed with?

Tags: picasa

I am looking for information on how Picasa was built as I would like to create a similar interface for my application.

Information can include programming language,UI design, etc.

Comment: i'm still hoping for the answer that gives the UI framework that was used.

Comment: Whatever it is, [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) uses the same UI framework: PSD and YTF files in the installation directory, and `ytWindow` class name.

Comment: ... possibly because [the same people worked on both Picasa and f.lux](https://forum.justgetflux.com/topic/42/android-version/9).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found this [The Beautiful Picasa UI is Made of Dynamic PSD Files](http://web.archive.org/web/20081120034208/http://www.secretrobot.com/blog/archives/2004/11/the_beautiful_p_1.html):

> I was snooping around in Picasa's "runtime" folder and found a bunch
>   of Photoshop .PSD files. Sure enough, large parts of the UI are built
>   in Photoshop. Layers are used to organize buttons, stand-ins, and
>   cursors. Roll-overs are achieved with image replacement similar to
>   JavaScript/DHTML. For example, the timeline view is just a 640x480
>   image with a tagged layer to hold the selected group's thumbnail and
>   custom cursors defined in their own layer set.
>
> Picasa's underlying graphics engine is most likely a simplified
>   "Photoshop runtime" with a DOM to make it easy to target tagged
>   elements imported from .PSD files. This is a smart architecture
>   because it provides rapid UI prototyping and a consistent
>   look-and-feel across different platforms. Designers can make changes
>   in Photoshop then re-launch Picasa to see the results. Even better,
>   end users can skin the application without having to learn any new
>   tools.
>
> The "runtime" folder also contains some simple scripts that bind UI
>   elements to their .PSD counterparts, and define layout placement and
>   visibility.

Comment: Wow, that is an odd design decision. I am going to have to disagree with the Blog author on this one. I don't think it's such a great idea.

Comment: Page not found. -1 for link-only answer. You could've summarized it.