# What language is Picasa written in?

Tags: programming-languages, desktop-application, picasa

This was asked [about a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613630/who-knows-what-picasa-is-programmed-with), but never really answered. It would be great to find out what language/gui framework was used to write Google's desktop Picasa app. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it was ancient Sumerian... or maybe that was just the documentation? ;)
...seriously, if I had to guess, I'd say it was probably C++.

Comment: +1 for wit, maybe QT for the UI?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a look at the Windows version and I'd guess C++ as well for most of the components which is indicated by

- a scan using [PEiD](http://www.peid.info/) that yields that npPicasa3.dll and qtsupport.dll have been created by the Visual C++ 8.0 compiler.
- Process Explorer showing that Picasa3.exe has an open handle to MSVCP80.dll, which is the *Microsoft C++ Runtime Libary*

Comment: Neat, I didn't know about PEiD! Thanks for that link!

Comment: qt support? sounds like they used QT.

Answer (score 1):

Windows and Mac both have native apps, while the Linux version runs under Wine, so i suppose they don't use something like Java. I guess that means the Windows version is written in C++ while the Mac one is written in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](http://code.google.com/apis/picasa/). Even though this API is deprecated, it suggests that Picasa's UI is coded in some proprietary XML format made by Google, with an Adobe Photoshop file as the icon.